# Visual studio installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

when i'm installing "visual studio 2010 xpress editon" , its asks to install all products one by one like c++, C#, web developer. but ater intsallatoion when they comes with different application. one for C# and another for web dev. I want all them in one. how to do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is to buy the Pro version, I thought that was one of the main differences.

Comment: That is the way Microsoft decided to package the express versions, The professional and above will have them integrated.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't have that.You can work on one environment at a time.

Answer (score 0):

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#2005.E2.80.932010_products):

> > Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010 Express consist of the following separate products

- Visual Basic Express
- Visual C++ Express
- Visual C# Express
- Visual J# Express (2005 only)
- Visual Web Developer Express
- Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone (2010 only)

[programmers'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166716/visual-studio-2012-express-vs-professional) post:

> > The biggest difference is that Express editions do not support plugins (No ReSharper, no add-ons). Additionally, the non-express versions are all combined, meaning you don't have to switch back and forth to get features from individual express versions if you have a project that crosses web, desktop, etc.